# Is Black Hat SEO On topic

Tags: discussion, support, suitable-question

I'm wondering if this site has any specific policy regarding black hat seo questions. This question could pop up in the future, and I figured that it might be a good idea to have it writen down. Also, I was thinking of asking a few questions about black hat seo, and I wanted to check to make sure that was OK.

Comment: It might be better if you provided an actual example or two of what you had in mind. It's one thing to ask if doing X might be seen as questionable. (This [has come up](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=black+hat) plenty already, and that's just the cases where the topic came up directly.) It's another to ask for tips on *implementing* "black hat" techniques. From what I've seen, those inquiries tend to get shot down pretty quickly.

Comment: @Su' txs, that was what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as the question is on-topic and doesn't violate any rules, and this topic meets both criteria, it's an acceptable question to ask. But as pointed out in the comments, doing so is done at the risk of getting lots of downvotes. Plus this community tends to rebuff those kinds of questions by telling the question asker to to avoid such techniques do to do the right thing by focusing on content instead.